# Weak Convergence in Infinite Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $H$ be an infinite Hilbert space.

Show: For all $x \in H$ with $\|x\|\leq1$, there exists a sequence $(u_n)$ in $H$ with $\| u_n\|=1 $ such that $u_n \rightharpoonup x$.

My attempt:

Since $H$ is infinite, there exists a countable subspace $K$ with $x\in K$.

By Gram-Schmidt, we can find a orthonormal basis $(y_n)$ for $K$.

Hence, $x=\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k y_k$ for some $a_k \in \mathbb{F}$

Let $u_n= \frac {\sum_{k=1}^n a_k y_k}{\|\sum_{k=1}^n a_k y_k \|}$.

Then $\| u_n\|=1$.

Hence, we are done.

Could someone please check my proof, and let me know if it makes sense?

If not, could you please let me know where it went wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: The problem with your attempt is that first it fails if $x=0$, in which case $u_n$ is not well-defined (because then $a_k=0$). Even if we assume that $u_n$ is well-defined, convergence in norm of the numerator—the $n$the partial sum— necessarily demands that $x$ lie in the unit sphere, in which case, clearly, $u_n$ actually converges in norm to $x$. Thus, you are left with when $x$ lies in the open unit ball. I have provided a solution (in its entirety for Banach spaces) in my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem actually holds generally in Banach spaces that are not Schur spaces—Schur spaces are spaces for which weakly converging sequences converges in norm. ((By well-known results due to James and Rosenthal, we know that infinite-dimensional Schur spaces contain a copy of $\ell^1$, hence they are not reflexive; in particular, Hilbert spaces are not Schur spaces)). I will therefore state your problem in its entirety and prove it in the affirmative.

First, trivially, if $x\in S_X$ (that is, $x$ lies in the unit sphere), then we only need set $x_n:=x$ and we are done; hence suppose  $x\in B_X$ (that is, $x$ lies in the open unit ball). We have the following theorem.

> THEOREM: Let $X$ be a Banach space that is not a Schur space and let $x\in B_X$. Then there exists $\{x_n\}\subset S_X$ such that $x_n\rightharpoonup x$.

The Special Case $x=0$:

Since $X$ is not a Schur space, it is necessarily infinite dimensional and has a weakly converging sequence, say $u_n\rightharpoonup u$ but $u_n\not\to u$. Without loss of generality, assume $u_n\ne u$ for all $n$, then define $$ x_n:=\frac{u_n-u}{\|u_n-u\|}\,.$$
Clearly $x_n\in S_X$ and $x_n\rightharpoonup 0$, and we’re done.

The General Case:

Now suppose $x\in B_X$, and thanks to the Special Case, let $y_n\in S_X$ and $y_n\rightharpoonup 0$. Define $$\alpha_n:=\sup\{\alpha>0:\alpha y_n\in B_X-x\}\,.$$
Observe that since $x\notin S_X$, then $\alpha_n>0$ and because $y_n\in S_X$ then $\alpha_n\le 2$ for all $n$. Now define $$x_n:=\alpha_n y_n +x$$ and note that by definition of $\alpha_n $ we must necessarily have $x_n\in S_X$; however, $\alpha_n$ is bounded and $y_n\rightharpoonup 0$, thus we have $x_n\rightharpoonup x$, as desired.

Comment: In the general case, why do we have $x \notin S_X$? If $x \in S_X$, does that mean $\|x\|=1$? Thanks!

Comment: No, that means $x\in B_X$ —written differently $\|x\|\ne 1$ or equivalently $\|x\|<1$——because the case $x\in S_X$ (which is the same as $\|x\|=1$) is trivial. (In fact, I see that my proof above still works even for $x\in S_X$, however, as I said, this case is trivial simply by setting $x_n:=x$ for all $n$).

Comment: Let me also remark that in Hilbert spaces (and generally, in spaces with the so-called Radon-Riesz property) sequential weak convergence and norm convergence agree in the unit sphere——that is, whenever $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ and also $\|x_n\|=\|x\|=1$, then necessarily we actually have that $x_n\to x$. Stated differently, for these spaces, one cannot even obtain a true weakly converging sequence in the unit sphere with its limit point also in the unit sphere: all such sequences always converge in norm.

Comment: @JackLeGrüß Why does the given sup exist? And what is $B_{X} - x$?

Comment: $B_X$ is the open unit sphere centered at the origin and (thus) $$B_X -x:=\{z-x:z\in B_X\}=\{w:\|w+x\|<1\}$$ is the open unit ball centered at $-x$. The supremum exists because of the triangle inequality: that is, on the one hand, $$\|\alpha y_n+x\|\le\alpha+\|x\|\,,$$ and therefore $\alpha y_n\in B_X-x $ when $\alpha <1-\|x\|$; on the other hand, $$\|\alpha y_n+x\|\ge|\alpha-\|x\||\,,$$ from which it follows that $\alpha y_n\notin B_X-x$ when $\alpha\ge 1+\|x\|$.